# How to remove unmatched row in html table using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have two tables. I want to delete unmatching rows. Compare with first column in Table1 and  compare with first column in Table2.

```
Table1

111   aaa
222   bbb
333   ccc

Table2

333  xxx
444  zzz
111  vvv

result of Table2

333 xxx
111 vvv
```

I tried some thing
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/m7v4tpnu/2/)

Please help me these

Thank you.

Comment: I guess this might help you [ADD/ Delete unmatching rows Dynamically](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/781851/Add-Delete-Rows-Dynamically-using-jQuery-in-ASP-NE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
var notrem = [];
$('#Table1 tr').each(function(){
   var currentRowHTML = $(this).find("td:first").html();

    $('#Table2 tr').each(function(i){
        var c= $(this).find("td:first").html();
        if(c == currentRowHTML ){
            notrem.push(i);
         }
    });
});

$('#Table2 tr').each(function(i){
    if(notrem.indexOf(i) < 0){
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Explanation:

First gather all indexes of Table2 that are equal and are not to be removed. Next iterate again and remove those that are not present in`notrem` array.

http://jsfiddle.net/ndru/m7v4tpnu/14/

Answer (score 1):

Check this solution ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m7v4tpnu/16/)):

```
var newTbl = $('#newTbl');
$('#Table1 tr').each(function(){
    var that = $(this);
    var td = that.find('td').eq(0);
    var a = td.text();
    var arr = [];
    $('#Table2 tr').each(function() {
        var that = $(this);
        var b = that.find('td').eq(0).text();
        arr.push(b);
    }); 
    if ($.inArray(a, arr) != -1) {
        var c = $('#Table2').find('td:contains(' + a + ')').next().text();
        newTbl.append('<tr><td>' + a + '</td><td>' + c + '</td></tr>');
    }
});
```

1. Get the text of the first cell of the first row of `Table1` and store it to a variable (`a`)
2. Loop through the second table and see if this variable matches with the text of any of the first cells of each row.
3. If any match found, append a new row to `newTbl` table with this variable as text of the first cell.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if this works for you - http://jsfiddle.net/ylokesh/m7v4tpnu/19/

**HTML**

```
<table id="T1">
    <tr><td>111</td><td>xxx</td></tr>
    <tr><td>222</td><td>www</td></tr>
    <tr><td>333</td><td>ttt</td></tr>
</table>

<table id="T2">
    <tr><td>444</td><td>www</td></tr>
    <tr><td>111</td><td>xxx</td></tr>
    <tr><td>333</td><td>ttt</td></tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#T1 tr').each(function(){
    var data = $(this).html();
    $('tr', '#T2').each(function(){
        if($(this).html()===data){
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```